# on the usage of 'connect'

Tags: single-word-requests, books

In one of the very first sentences of Gravity's Rainbow by Pynchon

> ...feeling metal nearer and farther rub and connect...

am I right that the word 'connect' is used as a noun here? if so, is it a standard use? what does it mean exactly, is it some sort of material? I'm puzzled because I could not find any entry for such a noun in e.g. the OED.

Comment: Sounds to me like the usage is verbish.  But you really didn't include enough context to say with any certainty.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not include enough context.

Comment: It sounds like headlinese. Construction kits used to come with instruction sheets treating transitive verbs as if they were intransitive. I'd suggest '... feeling pieces of metal further from and nearer to one's position rub and connect together.'

Comment: Connect in this context is a verb. One piece of metal is connecting with another piece of metal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more complete context is this:

> It is too late. The evacuation still proceeds... Inside the carriage, which is built on several levels, he sits in velveteen darkness. with nothing to smoke, feeling metal nearer and farther rub and connect, steam escaping in puffs, a vibration in the carriage's frame, a poising, an uneasiness...They have begun to move. They pass in line, out of the main station...

The author is obviously describing the [coupling of the carriages of a train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_coupling), where the cars are pushed together and the metal couplers, all along the train (nearer and farther), first touch, then connect.

It is a verb.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a fuller [quote](http://www.english.txstate.edu/cohen_p/postmodern/Literature/Openings/Pynchon.html):

> Inside the carriage, which is built on several levels, he sits in velveteen darkness, with nothing to smoke, feeling metal nearer and farther **rub and connect**

These are bare infinitives (i.e., they've lost their introductory *to) and they are objects of the gerund *feeling*, telling what the subject was feeling as he sat in the darkness, namely disparate pieces of metal rubbing against and connecting with each other.